# Are __instancecheck__ and __subclasscheck__ class methods or instance methods?

Tags: python

In the [Python Language Reference - 3. Data Model - 3.3.4 Customizing instance and subclass checks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks),
`__instancecheck__` and `__subclasscheck__` are both listed with their first parameter as `self` rather than `cls` despite [PEP 3119](https://peps.python.org/pep-3119/) always defining them with `cls`, indicating that they are a class method rather than an instance method.

For example, `__instancecheck__(cls, instance)` reimplements `isinstance(instance, cls)` with issubclass similarly implemented.

Which one of these definitions is correct? Are `__instancecheck__` and `__subclasscheck__` instance methods with their first parameter meant to be `self` or class methods with their first parameter meant to be `cls`?

I tried to search a bit deeper in the python interpreter using inspect as follows

```
>>> import inspect
>>> print(type.__instancecheck__)
<method '__instancecheck__' of 'type' objects>
>>> inspect.ismethod(type.__instancecheck__)
False
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(type.__instancecheck__)
FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'instance'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

What I found was that in the Python interpreter, `type`'s `__instancecheck__` method was implemented with `self` rather than `cls`. Also, it returned false on `inspect.ismethod()` for some reason I don't understand.

Comment: They're methods of metaclasses. In a metaclass, the instance is a class.

Comment: Got it thanks! It was the discrepancy between the PEP and Docs that was throwing me off, but that makes sense.

Comment: Metaclasses straddle the boundary. Whether you choose to call it `cls` or `self` is a matter of style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barmar answered my question above: "They're methods of metaclasses. In a metaclass, the instance is a class." and "Metaclasses straddle the boundary. Whether you choose to call it cls or self is a matter of style."

Comment: Can you try rephrasing in your own words?  It’s good to make sure that you understand the answer.